# Seed data in EF 2.1 with related entities

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.1, entity-framework-core-2.1

Using ASP.NET Core 2.1 and Entity Framework Core 2.1 I have the following entities:

```
public class Category {
  public Int32 Id { get; set; }
  public String Name { get; set; }
}

public class Post {
  public Int32 Id { get; set; }
  public Int32 CategoryId { get; set; }
  public String Title { get; set; }
  public String Content { get; set; }
  public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

For seeding Categories I have the following:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Category>().HasData(
  new { Id = 1, Name = "Reading" },
  new { Id = 2, Name = "Travelling" }
);
```

However, for seeding posts I am getting the data from YML files:

```
var posts = _service.GetPostsFromYMLFiles(path);

modelBuilder.Entity<Post>().HasData(posts);
```

The `posts` are taken from YML files and are the following:

```
new { CategoryName = "Reading", Title = "A", Content = "A Content" },
new { CategoryName = "Travelling", Title = "B", Content = "B Content" }
```

These YML files are created by a third party and I cannot change them.

To seed these posts I believe I need to:

1. Get the correspondent Category Id for each CategoryName;
2. Generate an ID for each post.

The step (2) seems easy but how can I accomplish step (1)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of seeding the categories in place, save them to a variable first:

```
var categories = new[] 
{
    new Category { Id = 1, Name = "Reading" },
    new Category { Id = 2, Name = "Traveling" }
};
```

Then, pass this to `HasData`:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Category>().HasData(categories);
```

With that, you can now query this list in memory to get the relevant categories while mapping your YML data to your `Post` entities:

```
var posts = _service.GetPostsFromYMLFiles(path);
modelBuilder.Entity<Post>().HasData(posts.Select((p, i) => new Post
{
    Id = i,
    Title = p.Title,
    Content = p.Content,
    CategoryId = categories.Single(c => c.Name == p.CategoryName).Id
});
```

`CategoryId` is non-nullable, so you probably want to create a fallback for if a particular category named in your YML does not actually exist. You may even consider seeding the categories themselves from the post YML, to ensure that everything in there actually exists:

```
var categories = posts.Select(p => p.CategoryName).Distinct().Select((c, i) => new Category
{
    Id = i,
    Name = c
}).ToArray();
```

Comment: I was just typing code and not paying attention. I've fixed it by passing an index to `Select`.

Comment: Will the value of `i` be set serially and dynamically in your select?

Comment: Serially. It's from `Select` itself, so it indexes the items as it iterates over them.

Answer (score 2):

> To seed these posts I believe I need to:
>
> Get the correspondent Category Id for each CategoryName;
>
> Generate an ID for each post.

Yes! You are correct! you have to use `CategoryId` instead of `CategoryName` in the `Post` because `CategoryId` is the relational Key, not `CategoryName`. So your YML content should be like as follows:

```
new {Id = 1, CategoryId = 1, Title = "A", Content = "A Content" },
new {Id = 2, CategoryId = 2, Title = "B", Content = "B Content" }
```

Then in the `OnModelCreating` of the `DbConext` as follows:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
      base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
      
      var posts = _service.GetPostsFromYMLFiles(path);

      modelBuilder.Entity<Category>().HasData(
          new { Id = 1, Name = "Reading"},
          new { Id = 2, Name = "Travelling" }
      );

      modelBuilder.Entity<Post>().HasData(posts);        
}
```

> These YML files are created by a third party and I cannot change them.

Then you have to write a custom service method where you will check every post in YMl file with `CategoryName` then you have to make new list of `Post` where you will replace `CategoryName` with `CateogryId` and its appropriate value as follows:

```
public class YmlPost
{
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
}


public class SeedDataService
{
    static List<Category> categoryList = new List<Category>()
    {
        new Category { Id = 1, Name = "Reading" },
        new Category { Id = 2, Name = "Traveling" }
    };

    public static List<Category> GetCategoriesForSeeding()
    {
       return categoryList;
    }
    public static List<Post> GetPostsForSeeding()
    {
        List<YmlPost> postListFromYML = _service.GetPostsFromYMLFiles(path);

        List<Post> posts = postListFromYML.Select((p, i) => new Post
            { 
              Id = i+1, // index is 0 based that's why you have to add 1.
              Title = p.Title,
              Content = p.Content,
              CategoryId = categoryList.Single(c => c.Name == 
                           p.CategoryName).Id
            }).ToList();
        return posts;
    }
}
```

Then in the `OnModelCreating` of the `DbConext` as follows:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
      base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
      
      var categories = SeedDataService.GetCategoriesForSeeding();
      modelBuilder.Entity<Category>().HasData(categories);
      
      var posts = SeedDataService.GetPostsForSeeding();
      modelBuilder.Entity<Post>().HasData(posts);
           
}
```